# Splitting a page vertically HTML CSS - with opposing colors

Tags: html, css

I am working with Jekyll for the first time and need some help with the styling.

I'm trying to create a page that splits down the middle vertically, the left half is black with white font, the right half is white with black font.

Comment: Please give us some code and maybe a picture of what you want to accomplish. A great way to show us the code is JSFiddle (JSFiddle.net).

Comment: You've got two answers now. :) It'd be great if you could accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left{float:left;width:50%;height:100%;color:#FFF;background:#000}
#right{float:right;width:49%;height:100%;color:#000;background:#FFF}
```

Answer (score 2):

See this example:

```
<div id="black"></div>
<div id="white"></div>
```

In your CSS,

```
#black{
    float:left;
    background-color:black;
    width:50%
    height:100%;
    color:white;
}
#white{
    float:right;
    background-color:white;
    width:50%
    height:100%;
    color:black;
}
```